# ipRefererBlocked error when my api key's IP configuration matches server ip for the request

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-console, youtube-data-api

I recently made a change to the IP address listed under my server key, because I now have a new server.

Now however I still keep getting an ipRefererBlocked error as if the new ip is not listed in the server key via api console.

Is this just a propagation issue or could there be a bug? It has been almost 24 hours since I updated the IP settings. Other people have said that removing the IP all together from the configuration would work but I'd rather not go that route.